# PostgreSQL json in character varying with []

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm having trouble with accessing elements in a postgreSQL database. In one column of the database, there are multiple json-like strings, wrapped with []. The entry looks like [json1,json2].

```
[{"measurementType":"U", "value":2}, {"measurementType":"I", "value":10}]
```

Is there any way to directly access the value of a certain measurementType?

edit: changed 'U' to "U"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast that value to a `jsonb` and then use `jsonb_array_elements` to unnest the elements in the array and apply a WHERE clause to get the `measurementType` you want:

```
select e.element ->> 'value' as value
from the_table t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.the_column::jsonb) as e(element)
where e.element ->> 'measurementType' = 'U'
```

Answer (score 1):

The [] are not a problem, that is legitimate JSON for representing arrays.  It is the single quotes which are the problem.

If there are no literal single quotes or double quotes in your data, then you can just turn the single quotes into double quotes and cast it to json or jsonb:

```
regexp_replace(foo,'''','"','g')::jsonb
```

At which point you can apply all the [usual functions and operators.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.ht)

It would be better to clean your data by altering the column type to jsonb using the above method, and fix your ingestion method.  As opposed to loading it broken and then converting it on the fly each time you need it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just noticed, that there was an error in my post. There are only double quotes - I'm very sorry for the confusion.
However, I still cannot access the data with 
SELECT 
     measurements::json->'measurementValue' as meas
FROM X;
Do you know why?